# The application crashes at button click

Tags: android

I just made this application and it crashes at button click...
Have no idea why...
This, so far,  should print 1 if selected 1, and 2 if 2, and so on.
This is main.xml and Activity.java file.

```
This is Main.xml file
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/spinnerprompt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:prompt="@string/spinnerprompt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttontext" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" >
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/versetext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

And Activity.java file

package arirang.today.proverbs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TodaysProverbsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner Spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.datelist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
}

public void onclick(View view){
    Spinner Type;
    String verse = "";
    Type = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("1")){
        verse = "1";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("2")){
        verse = "2";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("3")){
        verse = "3";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("4")){
        verse = "4";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("5")){
        verse = "5";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("6")){
        verse = "6";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("7")){
        verse = "7";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("8")){
        verse = "8";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("9")){
        verse = "9";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("10")){
        verse = "10";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("11")){
        verse = "11";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("12")){
        verse = "12";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("13")){
        verse = "13";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("14")){
        verse = "14";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("15")){
        verse = "15";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("16")){
        verse = "16";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("17")){
        verse = "17";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("18")){
        verse = "18";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("19")){
        verse = "19";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("20")){
        verse = "20";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("21")){
        verse = "21";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("22")){
        verse = "22";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("23")){
        verse = "23";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("24")){
        verse = "24";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("25")){
        verse = "25";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("26")){
        verse = "26";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("27")){
        verse = "27";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("28")){
        verse = "28";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("29")){
        verse = "29";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("30")){
        verse = "30";
    }

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("31")){
        verse = "31";
    }

    TextView AfterBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.versetext);
    AfterBox.setText(verse);


}
}
```

Thanks you for reading this is not short...^^

Comment: equals "Compares the specified object to this string and returns true if they are equal. The object must be an instance of string with the same characters in the same order", try using matches "Tests whether this string matches the given regularExpression."

Answer (score 0):

Please change function name your activity file onClick(View view)  instead of onclick(View view) ...

issue of case sensitive of function name....